# Security of external jar file in GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jar

I have created a GWT project which is successfully using an external jar file (see [GWT - Using external jars / Java Projects by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWTModules/article.html)‎ and [Adding external jar in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515459/adding-external-jar-in-gwt)).

When I use a library file like this, what happens when I compile the project and upload it to AppEngine?  Does the jar file get uploaded as it is, or does it get compiled into something else first?  And if the former, is it at any security risk of being downloaded without my control?

Answer (score 1):

Let's drop the "google-app-engine" part, it doesn't matter here. You use the library in GWT, on client side. App Engine is server side, with no direct connection to GWT (but due to the volume restrictions it is quite useful to utilize some client side execution like GWT).

Everything you use in GWT will be compiled to JavaScript, transferred to the client and executed there. Obviously you have no control over the result and what the client does with it.

But it will be next to unreadable. Plus the client does not get the JAR per se and he does not get everything that is inside the JAR.

So what really matters is if the library's license allows this and if there are secrets in the library code that are only intended to be used on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **his**'s answer is not quite correct. The "google-app-engine"-part matters a lot here. Technically, GWT compiles and obfuscates all of the Java code it needs. And it strips out everything that it doesn't need. So, from the JavaScript generated by GWT, it should indeed be quite impossible to reconstruct or maybe even recognize the library. But it turns out that if you use the Eclipse plugin to deploy your app, appcfg uploads all sorts of random stuff to the AppEngine servers, sometimes including the entire Java source of the project (client side code included).

To see what exactly it uploads when you do a deploy, check in your system's `temp`-directory while the upload is running. You will find an AppEngine staging directory there that contains everything to be sent.

For suggestions for ways around this, you can refer to the answers to a question that I asked earlier: [Removing unwanted uploads from AppEngine deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548064/removing-unwanted-uploads-from-appengine-deployment)

What I haven't checked is whether all the unwanted uploaded files end up in directories that are actually directly accessible from the internet.